# Inheritence - CSS Modules in React and Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, webpack, css-modules

Say I have a React module called `nav` which has multiple `<li>` and `<a>` tags nested within. With CSS Modules how can I have "inheritable" or "cascading" rules such as this:

```
nav {
    background: red;

    > li > a {
        background: green;    
    }
}
```

It seems i can only apply one style directly to one element?

Answer (score 0):

It's not [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) or [the cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) that your code example is demonstrating, it's the use of selector [combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators).

Your example shows SCSS code which supports [nesting](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3) so this:

```
nav {
    background: red;
    > li > a {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

is transpiled into:

```
nav {
    background: red;
}

nav > li > a {
    background: green;
}
```

CSS Modules isn't preventing you from using these combinators -- CSS Modules is a superset of CSS so the second example will work out of the box. The first example will work if used with SCSS.

It might be worth noting that a lot of the rational behind CSS Modules would suggest the above CSS is poor for at least two reasons:

1. Targeting tags

   - `nav`, `li` and `a` are all very generic so it's incredibly likely to conflict with other rules in all but the very smallest projects.
2. High specificity

   - `nav > li > a` is needlessly specific (and tightly coupled with the mark-up structure). In order for CSS to successfully scale it's generally considered good practice to reduce specificity so selectors aren't having to compete (!important).